# How to find and remove old redirects in a mod_rewrite setup?

Tags: apache, bash, mod-rewrite, logging, grep

I've got some sites on which we used mod_rewrite largely to 301 redirect old links to new relevant pages.

The problem is, we've got thousands of rules per site now, some of which are obscure in the extreme and have been around for years.  Then there are some which interfere with each other and/or create loops.  What fun.

What I'd like to do is to log mod_rewrite for a period - let's say a few weeks, and then parse through these logs to find actual redirects that have been used, and then remove any that aren't.

The issues are that:

a) it creates very large log files, as it logs at least one line (2 if you're using a more useful log level) for every request even if it's just passing through.

b) the logs aren't terribly helpful - the useful line appears to be say:

```
1.2.3.4 - - [15/Aug/2013:03:23:57 +1000] [www.mysite.com/sid#2b5174473a38][rid#2b51748a42d0/initial] (2) rewrite '/pete' -> '/pete-website/'
```

but since almost every line has the phrase "(2) rewrite" it's fairly hard to find the useful ones.

I guess I'll need to use grep to shrink the logs down to something useful, then a script to parse through the rewrite rules and find which aren't being used?

I guess the real question is, surely I'm not unique in this situation, but I can't find anyone else either asking about it or finding an answer anywhere else on t' web - anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [conditional log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#conditional).

In your `RewriteRule`'s you suspect to be old:

```
 RewriteRule /old/page /new/page [R=301,E=redirectinuse]
```

In your logging setup:

```
 CustomLog logs/old_redirections common env=redirectinuse
```